# QT communicate through QProcess with Notepad.exe

Tags: qt, communication, qprocess

I would like to start notepad.exe from QT and then for example write "Hello Notepad" to the input-area of Notepad from QT!

[image]

What I managed to do, is starting notepad from QT. But what ever I try I can't fill in the text in the Notepad-textedit area.

## .h-File:

```
    #ifndef MATLABPROCESS
    #define MATLABPROCESS
    
    #include "QObject"
    #include <QProcess>
    #include <QDebug>
    
    class MatlabProcess : public QObject{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        
        // enum State {IDLE, ERRORX, WRITING};
        //State myState;
        QProcess* myProcess;
        
        explicit MatlabProcess (QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
            myProcess = new QProcess(this);
            // myState = IDLE;
            QObject::connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), SLOT(writing_stream()));
        }
        
        Q_INVOKABLE bool startMatlab(){
            
            // QString program = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab.exe\"";
            QString program = "\"C:/FlorianK/notepad.exe\"";
            
            myProcess->start(program);
            if (!myProcess->waitForStarted(-1)) return false;
            
            qDebug() << "program started";
            
            return true;
        }
        
        Q_INVOKABLE bool stopMatlab(){
            //TODO
            return false;
        }
        
        Q_INVOKABLE bool writeSomething(){
            
            QByteArray script = "Hello Notepad\n";
            
            qDebug() << myProcess->write(script);
            qDebug() << myProcess->waitForFinished();
            QByteArray result = myProcess->readAll();
            
            qDebug() << "result: " + result;
        }
        
    private slots:
        void writing_stream() {
            
            if (!myProcess) return;
            
            QTextStream out(stdout);
            out << myProcess->readAllStandardOutput() << endl;
        }
    };
    
    #endif // MATLABPROCESS
```

Because I want to do this stuff from qml, I registered this class in main.cpp

```
qmlRegisterType<MatlabProcess>("com.myself", 1, 0, "MatlabProcess");
```

From qml I call startMatlab() and than writeSomething(). The qt-output for "writesomething" will be

```
14
```

than 30seconds will happen nothing and program freezes than following lines will be printed in Qt-output

```
false
"result: "
```

The Notepad-text-area stays empty.

Comment: have you read about how write works? It works on standard streams. Matlab seems to have some kind of interface there to work with while notepad does not. If notepad does not provide a interface to be used by other processes, this will not be possible for you

Comment: OK, thanks for your quick answer. I would be even happier to know how to write anything to matlab, as this is what I basically want to do. I thought it would be easier to start with notepad ... stupid idea.

Comment: the question is if matlab supports this either. The 14 can be an accident you get. You need to search if you can find some specification how other processes can interact with matlab.